# How to make a flare animation fullscreen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flare, rive

I recently made an animation using Flare.

I used **flare_splash_screen** package to use that animation as a splash screen in my flutter app.

The problem I am facing is that I am unable to make the animation full screen on devices with **notches** and **bezel-less** displays.

The animation **appears fullscreen** on devices like Google Pixel XL and iPhone SE. but not on devices like iPhone 11 Pro, iPhone 11 Pro Max.

The size of my ArtBoard is **1080x1920**

**I have tried everything like**

- Using Expanded
- Playing with weight and height
- Using a container and resizing that

but no matter what I do the animation is in the **middle of display** and **never fullscreen.**

any help would be truly appreciated

[image: This is the space animation is taking]

**Here is my code :**

```
    class Animation extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SplashScreen.navigate(
      name: 'assets/animations/mablac_attire.flr',
      next: (_) => AttireScreen(),
      until: () => Future.delayed(Duration(
        seconds: 1,
        milliseconds: 45,
      )),
      startAnimation: 'Opening',
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62144845/5789458